# Trying to set a couple variables from Firebase Field values... asynchronous function problem

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read a field from my Firestore Firebase Database and assign it to a global variable. However, the variable always seems to be the variable. I checked many forums and they all say this is an asynchronous function. This confuses me and I need help with my specific example.

```
func getDropDownOptions(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let Uid = user!.uid

    db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Uid).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                    if let data1 = document.data()["int1"] {
                        self.int1 = data1 as! String
                        if let data2 = document.data()["int2"] {
                            self.int2 = data2 as! String
                            if let data3 = document.data()["int3"] {
                                self.int3 = data3 as! String
                                if let data4 = document.data()["int4"] {
                                    self.int4 = data4 as! String
                                    if let data5 = document.data()["int5"] {
                                        self.int5 = data5 as! String
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

int1 thru int5 are already declared as vars. When I try to print them after calling this function, they just return the default value I set for them.

I have absolutely no clue what is the problem. Please help!